# SPRING LDAP - ODManager query returning size limit exceeded

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I am attempting to query Microsoft Active Directory Application Mode (ADAM) using Spring LDAP 1.3.2.  I am using the ODMManager to search ADAM.  I am getting the error

```
javax.naming.SizeLimitExceededException: [LDAP: error code 4 - Sizelimit Exceeded]; remaining name '/'
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3119)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3013)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2820)
```

It is not clear from the documentation how I can use the PagedResultsDirContextProcessor to process ODMManager searches.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working using Spring LDAP 2.0.1.RELEASE.  The Object Directory Mapper is now managed within the LdapTemplate.  I used the a custom ContextMapper to execute a search on the directory.  The mapper and the method are listed below.

1. Create Custom ContextMapper class.

   ```
   public class UserContextMapper implements ContextMapper {

       private static ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"spring-config.xml"});

       public Object mapFromContext(Object ctx) {
           Class<User> clazz = User.class;
           LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = (LdapTemplate) appContext.getBean("ldapTemplate");

           User user = ldapTemplate.getObjectDirectoryMapper().mapFromLdapDataEntry((DirContextOperations) ctx, clazz);
           return user;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a method that creates an LdapOperationsCallback and pages the results

   ```
   public List<User> getLdapQueryResult(final LdapName dn, final Filter filter) throws NamingException {
       final PagedResultsDirContextProcessor processor = new PagedResultsDirContextProcessor(getPageSize());
       final SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
       final UserContextMapper ucm = new UserContextMapper();
       searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
       return SingleContextSource.doWithSingleContext(
               ldapTemplate.getContextSource(), new LdapOperationsCallback<List<User>>() {
           @Override
           public List<User> doWithLdapOperations(LdapOperations operations) {
               List<User> result = new LinkedList<User>();
               do {
                   List<User> oneResult = operations.search(dn, filter.encode(), searchControls, ucm, processor);
                   result.addAll(oneResult);
               } while (processor.hasMore());
               return result;
           }
       });
   }
   ```